# How to make logo apear on left while nav is on the right

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML so I have tried using CSS (float right) and class navbar-right but to no avail, nav buttons always stay on the left. I tried looking up online and everyone says use float but for some reason it doesn't work.

CSS/HTML Code:

```css
.logo {
  margin-left: 75px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#nav-item {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: square;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="assets/logo.png" alt="PS"></a>
          <ul id="navigation" class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left{
 float: left; 
}
.right{
  float: right;
}
.nav{
  background: gray;
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<div class="left">
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/1508/PNG/64/mpvicon8bit64x64_104611.png">
</div>
<div class="right">
<button>
one
</button>
<button>
two
</button>
<button>
three
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Try adding float value to your css:

```
.logo {
  margin-left: 75px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
  float: left;
}
```

Should work, u can try adding `!important` next to float value.
For navbar i also don't recommend using list (`<ul><li>` options). try making clickable content as buttons and add class to the with float right.

Edit, adding code I promised:

Comment: I will be back at home in around 40 minutes then I will send you FSFiddle code for it.

Comment: @Falithh You can also just use the "Copy snippet to answer" button on the snippet to use the code the OP has provided...

Answer (score 0):

here is my navbar which have a logo in the left hope it will help you

this is the css file :-

```
    .navbar{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background-color: black; 
                top: 0;           
                
            }
    .logo{
                color: white;
                width: 20vw;
                padding: 0.5vw 1vh;
            }
            .logo img{
                width: 6vw;
                height: 5vh;
                margin-left: 2vw;
            }
            .leftlist{
                width: 30vw;
                padding: 0.9vw 2vh;
            }
            #search{
                padding: 0.3vw 1vh;
                border: 2px solid rgb(160, 255, 247);
                border-radius: 9px;
            }
            .rightnav{
                width: 60vw;
                padding: 0.8vw 2vh;
            }
            .rightnav a{
                color: white;
                font-size: 1.5vw;
                padding: 1.1vw 3.4vh;
                text-decoration: none;
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                transition: 0.6s ease;
            }
            .rightnav a:hover{
                color: rgb(250, 250, 164);
            }
```

this is the html file :-

```
     <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="trade/logo.jpeg" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="leftlist">
                    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
                     <button class="btn v-class-resp">Search</button>
                 </div>
                 <ul class="rightnav">
                    <a href="#" id="home">Home</a>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                    <a href="#detail">Details</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                    <a href="login.html" target="_blank">Log In</a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
```

Comment: let me know if this help's you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to move the text using your CSS specifically this code:

```
#nav-item {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
}
```

The problem with this is that you shouldn't use '#' before the class name. Instead use this:

```
.nav-item {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 75px;
}
```

Comment: @vedo What are you trying to do? Move the text all to the right or the logo?

Comment: i want to have logo on the left and all the text aka <li></li> on the right

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use float. And would rather try to use flexbox.

It may help to add the following.

```
nav { display:flex; }
.rightnav { margin-left:auto; }
```

I feel that this answers your question. But I believe there is many other things you need to consider to style the layout as you'd probably like.

Here is a nice overview of flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I have used Flexbox here. It is easy to understand and code. Try out it this way.

You can change the margin and padding in your own way.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  /*margin-left: 75px;*/
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/*#nav-item {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
}
*/
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: square;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
  <div class="header">
            <div>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="assets/logo.png" alt="PS"></a>
            </div>

            <div>
                <ul id="navigation" class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
                      <!-- <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div> -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, float left works fine, unless you use another CSS rule that replaces this.
I used your code with a few minor edits:

```html
<style>
.logo {
  margin-left: 75px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
  float:left;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navigation a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#nav-item {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 75px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: square;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="assets/logo.png" alt="PS"></a>
          <ul id="navigation" class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

... and everything looks good.